# User obfuscate/customize an app icon

Tags: android, iphone, user-controls, icons, customization

I'm working on an support application for patients with a highly **stigmatized** **chronic illness**, where the risk of **disclosure** is high.

So I was wondering if it's feasible to add a feature that enables the user to change the way the application **icon** looks on a **mobile** desktop.

For example: User downloads the mobile app, during initial application setup they get promoted to upload a png or choose from a predefined set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest using a 1x1 screen widget instead of icon. In the applications list the icon will not be changed but user can put a widget with whatever icon he wants to the home screen and launch the app with tapping it.

Hope this way will be useful in your case.

Comment: So essentially a shortcut, i've come across similar apps that does that.

So are you saying that changing the actual  icons after the app has been compiled isn't feasible.

Comment: I've looked for the similar feature previously and the desktop widget was the best possible workaround for me.